# MySQL returns empty set seemingly at random

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why MySQL is returning an empty set for only certain users in the following query. I have the same info entered in every single profile, and only a couple userid's will return a result.

```
SELECT userinfo.userid, userinfo.location, locations.locationsName, locations.locationsID FROM userinfo
INNER JOIN locations ON locations.locationsID = userinfo.userid
WHERE userinfo.userid = '$userid'
```

Here are my tables (there are more columns, but they're irrelevant to this search)

```
userinfo
userid | location 

locations
locationsID | locationsName
```

For example, I can open PHPMyAdmin and type in that query (changing the $userid). I made sure every single username has the same info entered (aside from having a different userid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're joining the LocationID to the UserID.

Based on your given schema, you probably want to join `userinfo.userid = location.userid`

Comment: Wow, talk about obvious! I need to step away from my computer for a bit. Thanks for the help....Actually it should be userinfo.location = locations.locationsName, regardless thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: We all do it. Sometimes you just need a different set of eyes.

Comment: @user1406951 Feel free to accept his answer then. It's a great way to thank the answerer and spares others time when they don't have to read a question and answers to find out that it's solved already.